# Explain the sequence in these Excel Fill Series

Tags: number-sequence

In Excel Fill Series if you input **23, 132, 2**
then 31.33333333, 20.83333333, 10.33333333, -0.166666667, -10.66666667....is generated

and if you input **13, 16, 17**
then 19.33333, 21.33333, 23.33333, 25.33333.. is generated as shown below

**What is the algorithm for number generation?**

[image: Series 1] [image: Series 2]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Can you please be more clear in your problem? What's the question? Where's that sequence from?

Comment: I am asking about how the given series is formed as in image. If 23,132, 2, then how 31.3333 is generated as next number?

Comment: And what is 20.83? The next number of the sequence?

Comment: yes numbers in the given image are automatically generated by excel if we give 23,132,2 as input for Fill Series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequences are a linear extrapolation of the 3 initial points as follows:

- the starting point is Backcalc<sub>2</sub> which is the average of the 3 initial points
- the Increment is the average of Actual<sub>2</sub>-Actual<sub>1</sub> and Actual<sub>3</sub>-Actual<sub>2</sub>

[image: Sequence]

Comment: Nice answer, but Could you please further explain how you got the Backcalc 62.83333? Thanks for you help

Comment: @Deepak - OK. Start at 52.33333. Going **down** the column, continue to subtract 10.5. Then going back **up** the same column, each number is increasing by 10.5.  So add 10.5 to 52.33333 to get 62.83333.

Comment: You algorithm satisfies correctly if we give input as three numbers. But if we give 4 numbers as input **23,1541,42,21** then this sequence is generated 30.5,-120, -270.5, -421, -571.5, -722, -872.5... Could you please explain the algorithm for this?

Comment: To match Excel with 4 or more input numbers, a proper linear regression calculation needs to be done.  The input numbers can be entered into [this calculator](http://knowpapa.com/trend-line/).  Then the Excel fill numbers can be matched by using the best fit equation.